# 525 SSL handshake failed when using Let's Encrypt with CloudFlare and nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, cloudflare, lets-encrypt

I am unfortunately getting a `525 SSL handshake failed` error on cloudflare when trying to access my site after trying to create a Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate.

I generated the certificate by running `certbot-auto certonly` then entering my email, domain, and webroot. Then I added the certificate files to my server block as seen below.

Below is the relevant nginx server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-G$
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    root /var/www/html/mydomain.com;
    autoindex on;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
}
```

The output of `ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com` if important:

```
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 543 Jan 13 12:44 README
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  41 Jan 13 13:14 cert.pem -> ../../archive/mydomain.com/cert3.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  42 Jan 13 13:14 chain.pem -> ../../archive/mydomain.com/chain3.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  46 Jan 13 13:14 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/mydomain.com/fullchain3.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  44 Jan 13 13:14 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/mydomain.com/privkey3.pem
```

Running `nginx -t` gives no errors.

My CloudFlare settings:

SSL - Full (strict)

Comment: Could be a lot of different things. You're config shows two domains, does the cert have the SAN field filled out for all domains?

Comment: I think I might have only put my domain.com and not we.myfomain.com as well, I'll fix that, but wouldn't the one I did setup work still?

Comment: Depends on what domain cloudflare is trying to connect to.

Comment: Grey-cloud the domain, flush your dns cache, and see if you get the same issue in a browser. That's not a fix, but a step in diagnosing.

Comment: Alright, for some reason, `listen 443 ssl` in another server block for a subdomain was what the issue was. When I removed that from the server block, I could access my site over ssl, but the certificate shown on chrome isn't the one I created, it is still CloudFlare's. Perhaps this is an issue with cloudflare interfering with with the `server_name`?

Comment: Unless that is intended? Because I'm connecting to cloudflare first, I would only see the cloudflare certificate but know that the cloudflare to server link is secure?

Comment: Have you ever got to resolve this issue, I'm running into the exact same thing.

Comment: @gomeow I'm running into a similar issue. Were you able to get this resolved?